# wireless interface stops working, netcfg reports no network found

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, netcfg

I'm having a recurrent issue with my Arch Linux installation: wireless will work for a few minutes and then randomly die.  When I try to restart it through wifi-menu I am informed there aren't any networks.

```
 > sudo wifi-menu
:: Scanning for networks                                                [FAILED] 
 > No networks found
```

Running netcfg directly, I recive:

```
sudo netcfg wlan0-2WIRE555
:: wlan0-2WIRE555 up                  [ BUSY ] Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Connection timed out
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Connection timed out
WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
> wpa_supplicant did not start, possible configuration error
```

The output of `lspci` is:

```
~ > lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 (rev ff)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Every time this happens, I have to restart in order to get internet working.  Is there some systemd command I can use to restart it manually?  Is this an issue I can resolve permanently?

Comment: Give us a little more info.  Give us the `lspci` output for the wireless interface itself.  `lspci` says this about my arch wireless interface: "05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5212/AR5213 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a Centrino chipset machine, but I do run Arch on my laptop, and I've experimented with a lot of wireless cards and drivers.

A little googling around shows me this:

- [Ubuntu people suspect a possible firmware error](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1919003)
- [Arch linux people give a driver parameter to try.](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=144842)
- [Latest firmware for Centrino can be had here.](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi)

It also looks like some laptops have an external wireless switch.  Ensure it's "on".

Comment: options iwlwifi wd_disable=1 (from the Arch linux link) seems to have done the trick. thanks!